# What is the purpose of Lucene's @ (anystring) optional regexp syntax

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I noticed this optional Lucene regex syntax, and wasn't sure what it's purpose was.  When performing a regex query in Lucene, you can enable `@` as a special character with the [ANYSTRING](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html#ANYSTRING) flag, like so:

```
new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "abc@"), RegExp.ANYSTRING);
```

Tried a few things, and it *seems* to behave the same as:

```
new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "abc.*"));
```

The [ElasticSearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) note that it can be used with other optional syntax to provide an "anything except" query, such as:

```
new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "ab(@&~(cd))"), RegExp.ALL);
```

But even this seems to work fine with `.*` instead:

```
new RegexpQuery(new Term("text", "ab(.*&~(cd))"), RegExp.ALL);
```

So why does this optional `@` syntax exist?  Is it just an alias for `.*`, or is there some subtle difference between the two that I am missing?

Comment: It looks like @ matches the entire string, but don't know if it is used like a zero-width assertion or not. So `@&~(cd)` looks like anything _but_ the string `cd`.

Comment: @sln - Good thought, but doesn't seem to be a zero-width assertion (`a@c` matches "abc").  `.*&~(cd)` also seems to match anything but "cd", as well (matches "cda" and "acd", but not "cd").  `&` is an intersection, so `(a.*)&(.*c)` matches "abc".

Comment: Doc's look very bizzar.